# How can I print out the max nos in each column of a numpy array in an object using python?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have the below numpy array

```
[[7, 0, 0, 6],

 [5, 6, 6, 1],

 [4, 1, 6, 7],

 [5, 3, 4, 7]]
```

I want to find the max no in each column using np.max and then print out the result in an object such that output will be as shown below

`[7, 6, 6, 7]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `arr` is your array, then you just need to use the `max` function, indicating the chosen axis:

```
arr.max(axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([7, 6, 6, 7])
```

If you want a list instead of a numpy array:

```
arr.max(axis=0).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[7, 6, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the transposed array and look for the max value with `np.max()`:

```
import numpy as np

m =np.array([[7, 0, 0, 6],

 [5, 6, 6, 1],

 [4, 1, 6, 7],

 [5, 3, 4, 7]])

out = [np.max(i) for i in m.transpose()]
print(out)
```

**Output:**

```
[7, 6, 6, 7]
```

Comment: why not use the `axis` parameter of `np.max`?

Comment: @hpaulj Because it doesn't provide the same output with this solution: `[7, 6, 7, 7]`

Comment: Did you try `axis=0`?  (see the other answer)

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, but it only works without comprehension

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

m =np.array([[7, 0, 0, 6],

 [5, 6, 6, 1],

 [4, 1, 6, 7],

 [5, 3, 4, 7]])


#list
max_numbers = [max(x) for x in m]

#array
max_num_array = np.array(max_numbers)
```